# jQuery - Pass variable as options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-scrollify

I have a variable I have generated (with help from a previous question/answer) that looks like this...

```
var ids = $(".myelement").map(function() {
  return '#' + $(this).closest(".panel").prop("id");
}).get().join(', ');

console.log(ids);
```

The output returned in the console log is...

```
#element1, #element2, #element3
```

I am now trying to use this variable as an option when initializing a jquery plugin like this...

```
$.scrollify({
    section : ids,
});
```

This is not working and is just returning 'ids' instead of the value of ids. Am I doing it incorrectly or does the ability to accept the variable depend on the jQuery plugin itself?

Comment: Does it work if you do :  `$.scrollify({ section : #element1,#element2,#element3" });`

Comment: Yep, works correctly when I enter them manually. Looking at the code I can see it just prints 'ids' instead of the value of the variable

Comment: Had a quick look at jquery-scrollify and it correcltly does `$(selector).each`

Comment: There's nothing obvious with the code provided - could it be the order that it's run?  Hard to tell when separate snippets.  eg is there an ajax call?

Comment: I'm wondering if it could be as simple as a scope issue?

Comment: Should work https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/ge034w1m/81/

Comment: If `var ids` is not inside the same scope, then yes, it would fail.  Just before your `$.scrollify({` line, add `alert(ids);` (or `console.log`) to see what it is at that point (or use a debugger ofc).   Without seeing more code, can't tell if that's the issue, but sounds likely.